# Methods present in Frame class, which extends JFrame, can't be invoked in main()

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe

The code given below gives error (`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisible(boolean) from the type Window`) :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

While this one compiles fine :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    Frame() {
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I say `Frame extends JFrame`, this means that Frame inherits all the methods from JFrame (loosely saying), including `setVisible(boolean)` . So why can't I invoke `setVisible(true)` in `main()` , while I can do so in other methods?

Comment: `static` means, that there is one instance of the method, no matter, if there are any objects of this class. You cannot call a method which is not static, if the method you are calling from is static, especially when there is no object initialised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in the exception message.

The `setVisible` method is an instance method on `JFrame`

in `public static void main`, you are in a static context, so there is no instance of `Frame` to call `setVisible` on.

You could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame().setVisible(true);
}
```

because then you have an instance

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html might help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to call a method from `main()` which is as you can see static. However the `setVisible()` method is not static.

The error you are getting is exactly explaining that. In a static context you can only call static method. `setVisible()` is not static therefore you need to have an instance of your Frame class in order to call the method. Could be in your main:

```
Frame myFrame = new Frame()
myFrame.setVisible(true)
```

Disclaimer: sorry for any mistake you may see on this answer I am on the phone.

Hope it helps.